# Is there a way to clean up all variables, even local variables, inside a Firebase Python Cloud Function?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, artificial-intelligence

I'm using Firebase for a web application and especially Firebase Cloud Functions which helps me to start a function when a document (a picture here) is added to a collection (named `images/`).

The function is a basic `onDocumentCreated` function but I'm using **Tensorflow** to analyse the image which has just been push in my database. The problem is that, first predict try works well but when it's finished and I launch a second one, the function return the same prediction and it's this for almost all the following prediction.

Here is the python code for a better understanding :

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'  # Ignore TensorFlow warnings
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'  # Allow GPU memory growth

# The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and set up triggers.
from firebase_functions import firestore_fn, https_fn, options

# The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
from firebase_admin import initialize_app, firestore
import google.cloud.firestore

#AI imports
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


@firestore_fn.on_document_created(document="images/{pushId}",min_instances=0,max_instances=10,timeout_sec=120, memory=options.MemoryOption.GB_4, region="europe-west9", concurrency=1)
def findSpecies(event: firestore_fn.Event[firestore_fn.DocumentSnapshot | None]) ->None:
    """Listens for new documents to be added to /images. If the document has
    an "url" field, creates an "species" field containg the contents of
    species on the picture."""

    # Get the value of "url" if it exists.
    if event.data is None:
        return
    try:
        url = event.data.get("url")
    except KeyError:
        # No "url" field, so do nothing.
        return

    # Set the "species" field.
    print(f"Predicting {event.params['pushId']}: {url}")
    espece = predict(url)
    event.data.reference.update({"species": espece})
    


def predict(image_path):

    try:
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model.h5')
        img_path = image_path
        file_name = "image_to_predict"
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(tf.keras.utils.get_file(file_name, img_path), target_size=(224, 224))
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

        predictions = model.predict(img)

        top1_indices = np.argsort(predictions[0])[-1:][::-1]
        
        top1_labels = [k for k in top1_indices]

        print("Most probable class:", f"{top1_labels[0]}")

        return(f"{top1_labels[0]}")
        
    except:
        return("OnError")
```

After a lot of research, I've discovered that because of the way instances in Firebase works, my function `load_img()` is not always downloading the image file and this line is *"skipped"*. The program continue to run with the previous value of `img` and that's why my return is the same as the last prediction.

*First prediction try logs :*

```
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:43:35.925285Z Downloading data from https://LinkToMyFirstPicture
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:43:36.156716Z 8192/556425 [..............................] - ETA: 0s
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:43:36.156729Z 556425/556425 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step
INFO 2023-11-23T19:43:36.530603Z Default STARTUP TCP probe succeeded after 1 attempt for container "find-species-1" on port 8080.
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:43:42.256557Z 1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:43:42.256574Z 1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:43:42.260243Z Most probable class : 18
```

*Second prediction try logs (directly goes to `model.predict()`):*

```
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:44:04.683794Z 1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:44:04.683810Z 1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step
DEFAULT 2023-11-23T19:44:04.685277Z Most probable class : 18
```

I already try to use async function, While loop to wait until the end of the download, changing concurrency number to 1, changing function timeout... but nothing solved my problem.
I have the feeling that my `img` variable is stored in memory but I don't know why, because it's not a global variable.

The two pictures are completely different and when I run this separately on my computer, both predictions are correct.

I hope someone can help me on this.

Thank you in advance.